# Flutter/Dart not waiting for response

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an alert dialog, that returns true or false (if OK or Cancel is clicked).  When called null is assigned immediately and the code continues (despite the method being await... ing).

I have missed something obvious, but can not see it.

Here is the alert code...

```
static choiceAlert(BuildContext context, String _message) {
AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
  title: Text('Alert!'),
  content: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: ListBody(
      children: <Widget>[Text(_message)],
    ),
  ),
  actions: <Widget>[
    FlatButton(
      onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, true),
      child: Text('OK'),
    ),
    FlatButton(
      onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
      child: Text('Cancel'),
    ),
  ],
);
showDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierDismissible: false,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return alert;
  },
);
```

here is the request...

```
_discardSelectedAircraft() async {
String _message =
    'Are you sure.  This is irreversible, you will loose all data.';
bool _areYouSure = await Alerts.choiceAlert(context, _message);
if (_areYouSure == true) { do stuff...
```

So in a debug session I see null assigned to _areYouSure and hence the condition _areYouSure==true is never true.

I would have thought that the code would wait at `bool _areYousure =`... as it is marked await?  Yes the bool is created in memory first and assigned null but why is true not being returned to it from my alert dialog from the line

```
onPressed: ()=> Navigator.pop(context, true),
```

One other question I have if anyone wishes to throw it in, should I be using the following line instead, which is considered more correct as they seem to do the same thing?

```
onPressed: ()=> Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(context, true),
```

Thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about restructure your code as below ?

```
  static choiceAlert(BuildContext context, String _message) {    
      return showDialog(
    context: context,
    child: AlertDialog(
            .....
        child: ListBody(...)));
  }
```

Comment: OK, perfect thanks.  Could you if you have a moment share where my code was in error

Comment: Your problem is miss to return `showDialog`.

Comment: Excellent, thanks.  I can see that your code is more 'flutter like', and follow the error.